# Load different (debug or release) AAR inside a module depending on build variant

Tags: android, gradle

I have the following app project:

```
myapplication
    - app
    - mymodule
        - build.gradle
        - lib-debug.aar
        - lib-release.aar
```

The content of myapplication/mymodule/build.gradle is below:

```
configurations.maybeCreate("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('lib-release.aar'))
```

Now, what I want to do is load either `lib-release.aar` or `lib-debug.aar` depending on the app's Build Variant.
How do I do this check inside my `mymodule` module?